# Save data into Android SQLite Database when app is killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am troubled by the following issue in my Android Application (Java).

I have 3 activities, let's assume A, B and C.
The Activity A has two buttons : New Game and Resume Last Game.
The New Game button leads to Activity B, where the user enters some data, and from Activity B we go to Activity C.
The Resume Last Game button can directly lead to Activity C by reading the appropriate data from the database, if Activity C was killed in the middle of the game.

My problem is that I don't know to handle the code in Activity C, when  the whole app is killed by swiping, so exactly at that moment I can populate my database.

As far as I've tried, onDestroy() method is not called at that moment.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try using `onStop` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the activities life cycle, and I do recommend you to do handle it at the onDestroy() method. You can check the next link for more info.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Yes I've studied about lifecycles, but when I kill the app by swiping, onDestroy() is not called. Moreover, at the documentation it says : Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!

Comment: Yes, sorry, you should use the onStop() method instead.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I eventually used onPause(). It always gets called, so I handled my code in there and it works fine!